# Silverstripe DependentDropdownField issue

Tags: php, silverstripe

I need some help with the DependentDropdownField module.
I am using a Front end form on NewListingPage.php to create new 'Item' DataObjects, each Item is assigned a CategoryPage & SubCategoryPage for display filters and the page structure in the CMS is as follows.

```
- CategoryPage (This Page lists all child Sub Category Pages)
-- SubCategoryPage (This Page lists all related Item DataObjects)
```

When creating a new Item using NewListingPage.php, the user must first select the Category and SubCategroy. I want to use the DependentDropdownField to assign these pages to the DataObject.

This is my code:

NewListingPage.php

```
public function NewItemForm() {

    // Get the Lottery Feed
    $map = LotteryFeed::get()->map('ID','Title');

    // Get the Child Pages of the selected Category
    $subcategorySource = function () { 
        $subcategory = SubCategoryPage::get()->map('ID','Title'); 
        return $subcategory->filter('ParentID', $parent_)->sort('Date', 'DESC')->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray();
    };

    // Create the fields
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('Title', 'Product Name'),
        TextField::create('Description', 'Product Description'),
        TextField::create('Brand', 'Product Brand'),
        TextField::create('Year', 'Product Year'),
        OptionsetField::create('LotteryFeedID', 'LotteryFeed', $map, $map[0]),
        $categoryField = DropdownField::create('CategoryPage', 'Select a Category', CategoryPage::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', 'Title'))->setEmptyString('- Please Select -'),
        DependentDropdownField::create('SubCategoryPage', 'Select a Sub Category', $subcategorySource)->setEmptyString('-- Please Select --')->setDepends($categoryField),
        TextField::create('Price', 'Price'),
        FileAttachmentField::create('ProofImage', 'Proof Image'),
        FileAttachmentField::create('Images', 'Product Images')
    );

    // Create actions
    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create('submit', 'Create New Item')
    );

    $required = new RequiredFields('Name', 'Description');
    $form = new Form($this, 'NewItemForm', $fields, $actions, $required);

    return $form;
}
```

The result of this code is the Category Dropdown gets all Category Pages, but the SubCategory Dependant Dropdown lists only the EmptyString twice.

If I change the code to the following I can list all CategoryPages and all Sub Category Pages, but there is no dependancy on selection of the CategoryPage.

```
public function NewItemForm() {

    $map = LotteryFeed::get()->map('ID','Title');

    // Create fields
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('Title', 'Product Name'),
        TextField::create('Description', 'Product Description'),
        TextField::create('Brand', 'Product Brand'),
        TextField::create('Year', 'Product Year'),
        OptionsetField::create('LotteryFeedID', 'LotteryFeed', $map, $map[0]),
        $categoryField = DropdownField::create('CategoryPage', 'Select a Category', CategoryPage::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', 'Title'))->setEmptyString('- Please Select -'),
        DependentDropdownField::create('SubCategoryPage', 'Select a Sub Category', SubCategoryPage::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', 'Title'))->setEmptyString('-- Please Select --')->setDepends($categoryField), 
        TextField::create('Price', 'Price'),
        FileAttachmentField::create('ProofImage', 'Proof Image'),
        FileAttachmentField::create('Images', 'Product Images')
    );

    // Create actions
    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create('submit', 'Create New Item')
    );

    $required = new RequiredFields('Name', 'Description');
    $form = new Form($this, 'NewItemForm', $fields, $actions, $required);

    return $form;
}
```

I get that the function must evaluate the child pages of the selected Category, but I'm no PHP expert and cannot fathom how to do it.